# How can i send an String to my pcs port? tcp/ip

Tags: c#, vb.net, tcp, ip

I am trying to make a program in vb net that connects to the local ip 127.0.0.1 and sends a string to port 6680, waits for a response (msgbox), sends a string again and waits for a response again (msgbox) but I can't do it, could someone help me?
I want somthing like this with no classes and no methods, all in the main:

1. Connection to the Local Ip (127.0.0.1)
2. Send String to a port 6680 "String"
3. Write the response with a msgbox
4. Send String to the same port 6680 "String"
5. Write the response with a msbox
   Thank you!

I tried this but it didn't work, it hangs:

```
             Dim client As TcpClient = New TcpClient("127.0.0.1", port)

            ' Buffer to store the response bytes.
            Dim data As Byte()

            ' String to store the response ASCII representation.
            Dim responseData As String = String.Empty

            ' Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
            Dim Stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
            Stream.ReadTimeout = 1000
            Dim bytes As Int128 = Stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length)


            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes)
            'responseData = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(data, 0, bytes);

            MyData = responseData.Replace("\r\n", "")
            Stream.Close()
            client.Close()

            MsgBox(MyData)
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot step #2.

Comment: If you just want to send messages between computers I would suggest using a higher level protocol. Http, gRPC, MQTT, there are plenty to chose from. If you insist on TCP I would recommend reading [Stephen clearys TCP FAQ](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/tcpip-net-sockets-faq.html).